# Wacom Intuos CTH-490CK

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xsetwacom

I am trying to get my *Wacom Intuos CTH-490CK* up and running under Arch Linux. The device is recognized and everything but the buttons work. However, most guides suggest to install the proper kernel module, which is not necessary when using a recent kernel (*4.9.8-1* in my case). I read that removing [libwacom](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Libwacom) and just installing [xf86-input-wacom](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xf86-input-wacom) and [input-wacom-dkms](https://github.com/cyberang3l/input-wacom-dkms) might fix my issues ([post in german Arch Linux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.de/viewtopic.php?id=25263)), but trying to remove *libwacom* leaves me with the following error:

> error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
>   :: libinput: removing libwacom breaks dependency 'libwacom'

Forcing the deletion of the package (`pacman -Rdd libwacom`) leaves me without mouse and keyboard or any external input devices. As I don't see a Wacom device in */dev* I added a new udev rule:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-wacom.rule 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0084", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos5-s"
```

This didn't work either. I also tried a manual setup using [xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg):

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-wacom.conf 
Section "InputDevice"
    Driver        "wacom"
    Identifier    "stylus"
    Option        "Device"       "/dev/input/wacom"   # or the corresponding event?? for a static setup
    Option        "Type"         "stylus"
#    Option        "USB"          "on"                 # USB ONLY
#    Option        "Mode"         "Relative"           # other option: "Absolute"
    Option        "Vendor"       "WACOM"
#    Option        "tilt"         "on"  # add this if your tablet supports tilt
    Option        "Threshold"    "5"   # the official linuxwacom howto advises this line
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
    Driver        "wacom"
    Identifier    "pad"
    Option        "Device"       "/dev/input/wacom"   # or the corresponding event?? for a static setup
    Option        "Type"         "pad"
#    Option        "USB"          "on"                  # USB ONLY
#    Option        "Mode"         "Relative"            # other option: "Absolute"
    Option        "Vendor"       "WACOM"
#    Option        "tilt"         "on"  # add this if your tablet supports tilt
    Option        "Threshold"    "5"   # the official linuxwacom howto advises this line
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
    Driver        "wacom"
    Identifier    "touch"
    Option        "Device"       "/dev/input/wacom"   # or the corresponding event?? for a static setup
    Option        "Type"         "touch"
#    Option        "USB"          "on"                  # USB ONLY
#    Option        "Mode"         "Relative"            # other option: "Absolute"
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to get the four hardware buttons on the tablet working and how I can bring up a device in */dev*? Please find additional information below. If you need more just let me know,

```
$ lsusb | grep -i wacom
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:033c Wacom Co., Ltd

$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pen stylus      id: 15  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Finger touch    id: 16  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pad pad         id: 17  type: PAD

$ dmesg | grep -i wacom
[   18.071428] input: Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:056A:033C.0005/input/input24
[   18.071554] wacom 0003:056A:033C.0005: hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos PTS] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[   18.073731] input: Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:056A:033C.0006/input/input28
[   18.073852] input: Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:056A:033C.0006/input/input29
[   18.073980] wacom 0003:056A:033C.0006: hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos PTS] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1

$ lsmod | grep -i wacom
wacom                  90112  0
hid                   114688  6 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,wacom,hid_logitech_hidpp
led_class              16384  6 iwlmvm,asus_wmi,sdhci,wacom,input_leds,asus_wireless
```